# Bootstrap v4 - btn-block vertical spacing?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

What would be the best way to set vertical spacing on buttons with class `btn-block`?  I am finding the buttons don't have any vertical spacing in mobile view.

```
<li class="nav-item">
 <button type="button" id='reset_btn' class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm btn-block">Reset</button>
</li>
```

Comment: line-height? or maybe padding or margin around them

Comment: padding or margin between buttons...

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve ?  any screenshot/img

Comment: words seem to be enough...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want spacing between them just add `mb-2` or something similar margin wise to the `li` elements.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<ul class="nav flex-column ">
  <li class="nav-item mb-2">
   <button type="button" id='reset_btn' class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm btn-block">Reset</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item mb-2">
   <button type="button" id='reset_btn' class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm btn-block">Reset</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item mb-2">
   <button type="button" id='reset_btn' class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm btn-block">Reset</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
btn btn-primary btn-sm btnspace
```

I use this to keep space between buttons.

Comment: is `btnspace` is valid class of bootstrap 4?

Comment: try margin-left replacing btnspace, or margin-right. you have to define margin in css